# How get just text from ul li?

Tags: php, html, dom, html-lists

I am first time on this forum soo hello ;)
I am developing my first professional web page and I have to get text from li element. I am using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser Manual.

```
<ul class="siTimeToEnd">
    <li class="left smaller timeInfo">
        <strong>sth</strong>

         foo bar 


    </li>
</ul>
```

I would like get only 'foo bar' without text in strong attribute.
My code:
    `$date = $page->find("div[id=siWrapper] ul.siTimeToEnd li.timeInfo");`

The result it's:

```
dot (u know dot ;)) <strong>sth</strong> foo bar<br/>
```

I would get just:

```
foo bar
```

I am sorry for my English.

Comment: Can you edit the HTML? You could try <li class="left smaller timeInfo"><strong>sth</strong> <span>foo bar</span> in HTML. And in PHP: $page->find("div[id=siWrapper] ul.siTimeToEnd li.timeInfo span");

Comment: No I Can't. That's not my page ;(

Comment: Try `$date = $page->find("div[id=siWrapper] ul.siTimeToEnd li.timeInfo")->last_child();`, maybe you get the last TextNode.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way of handling this is, if the page is well-formed xhtml, you can handle it by using xpath.

For example,

```
foreach ($page->xpath("//li") as $date) {
        echo $date;
 };
```

should get you all `<li>`  elements.

If you need a good reference for how to search using xpath expressions, this is a pretty good one:   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it ;)
I use strip_tags, substr ;)